# Visual Studio Code create an empty line under

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the title says, is there a way to create an empty line under while moving all the code 1 line down?

For example, I want to create an empty line under the first div I'd need to go to the end of the line and hit enter to create a new empty line while moving everything down. As far as I can tell VSC does not have this shortcut but I'm new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

`<div id="showcase">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="showcase-content">
                    <h1><span class="text-primary">Enjoy</span> Your Stay</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quia sapiente molestiae voluptates dolorem deserunt!</p>
                    <a class="btn" href="about.html">About Our Hotel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`